# What is the efficient way to escape from "Division by zero error"

Tags: php

I have written a rating system function for products and it used to throw a "Division by zero error" so in order to escape that error I have decided to implement it this way, I would like to know if it is a good way to escape from that error

```
$ratingNumber = 10; 
$count = 0;

$average= $ratingNumber / isset($count)
```

Comment: `isset()` returns a boolean (True or False) (1 or 0)

Answer (score 1):

It wont work as you intended.

isset() checks if a variable, well, is set. You set 0 to $count then isset will always return true in this case.

You could do this instead:

```
function division($a, $b) {
   if($b === 0) {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException('Argument $b should not be 0.');
   }

   return $a/$b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid the division if `$count = 0`. You can try it in the following way.

```
$ratingNumber = 10; 
$count = 0;

if($count > 0){
  $average= $ratingNumber / $count;
}
```

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation of the solution, explaining what was wrong with their current implementation and how yours solve their issue. It also helps future visitors that have similar but not identical issues to understand the solution.